# Updating LayoutParams has no effect in some devices

Tags: java, android, multithreading, view, layoutparams

I am updating the top margin of a view at runtime, and it works fine in my device (Xperia S)
But when I test it on the Xperia Arc S or Nexus One, it doesn't update the margin!
I have a thread that increments a "position" integer. Every time it increments, it calls this for updating the view:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
            myView.setText("position: "+position);
            params.topMargin=position;
            myViewLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
          }
    });
```

The text is updated, but the margin doesn't!
I already tried to invalidate the view, but it still doesn't update the layout params.

This is how it should look like, and how it looks in my phone (Xperia S):

[image]

and this is how it looks in the Xperia arc s and nexus one:

[image]

As you see, the view stays at the top/left corner, and doesn't update the top margin.
I debugged it and the margin does get increased, so the view is just not updating the layout params!